# Using a Case statement within the values section of an Insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-update, case-statement

Please forgive my ignorance and poor SQL programming skills but I am normally a basic SQL developer.

I need to create a trigger off the insertion of data in one table to insert different data into another table.

Within this trigger I need to insert certain data into the new table based upon values within the newly inserted data from the original table. I am totally confused on this. i thought I would be creative and use a case statement within teh Values section but it is not working.

Can anyone please help me on this? (below is the code for the trigger that I have as of now)

```
    INSERT INTO dbo.WebOnlineUserPeopleDashboard
    (
        ONLINE_USERACCOUNT_ID,
        ONLINE_ROOMS_DIRECTORY,
        ONLINE_ROOMS_LIST,
        ONLINE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT,
        ONLINE_ROOMS_MANAGEMENT,
        ONLINE_MAILINGLIST_DIRECTORY,
        ONLINE_MAILINGLIST_LIST,
        ONLINE_MAILINGLIST_MEMBERS,
        ONLINE_MAILINGLIST_MANAGER,
        ONLINE_PEOPLESEARCH_DIRECTORY
    )
VALUES
    IF (SELECT ONLINE_PEOPLE_FULL_ACCESS FROM INSERTED) = 1
        BEGIN
            SELECT
                ONLINE_USERACCOUNT_ID,
                1,
                1,
                1,
                1,
                1,
                1,
                1,
                1,
                1
            FROM INSERTED
        END
    ELSE IF (SELECT ONLINE_PEOPLE_FULL_ACCESS FROM INSERTED) = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT
                ONLINE_USERACCOUNT_ID,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0
            FROM INSERTED
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT
                ONLINE_USERACCOUNT_ID,
                CASE --DIRECTORY
                    WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_FULL_ACCESS = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_VIEW = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_ADD = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_UPDATE = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_DELETE = 1
                        THEN 1
                    WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_FULL_ACCESS = 0
                        THEN 0
                END,
                CASE
                    WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_VIEW = 1
                        THEN 1
                    WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_VIEW = 0 
                        THEN 0
                END,
                CASE
                    WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_ADD = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_UPDATE = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_DELETE = 1
                        THEN 1
                    WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_ADD = 0 AND ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_UPDATE = 0 AND ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_DELETE = 0
                        THEN 0
                END,
                CASE
                    WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_MANAGEMENT_FULL_ACCESS = 1
                        THEN 1
                    WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_MANAGEMENT_FULL_ACCESS = 0
                        THEN 0
                END,
                CASE
                    WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_FULL_ACCESS = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_VIEW = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_ADD = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_UPDATE = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_DELETE = 1
                        THEN 1
                    WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_FULL_ACCESS = 0
                        THEN 0
                END,
                CASE
                    WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_VIEW = 1
                        THEN 1
                    WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_VIEW = 0
                        THEN 0
                END,
                CASE
                    WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_ADD = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_UPDATE = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_DELETE = 1
                        THEN 1
                    WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_ADD = 0 AND ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_UPDATE = 0 AND ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_DELETE = 0
                        THEN 0
                END,
                CASE
                    WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_ADD = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_UPDATE = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_DELETE = 1
                        THEN 1
                    WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_ADD = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_UPDATE = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_DELETE = 1
                        THEN 0
                END,
                CASE
                    WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_PEOPLE_SEARCH = 1
                        THEN 1
                    WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_PEOPLE_SEARCH = 0
                        THEN 0
                END
            FROM INSERTED
        END 
    END
```

Comment: **NEVER code a trigger for single insertion** it will eventually bite you! perhaps you app inserts only one today, what about some time in the future, maybe a year for now you'll have some script insert a bunch or you'll import a file, etc. **your selected answer trigger will not fail with an error and a rollback, but you will just get wrong data, which is way worse!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
IF (SELECT ONLINE_PEOPLE_FULL_ACCESS FROM INSERTED) = 1

    INSERT INTO dbo.WebOnlineUserPeopleDashboard 
    ( 
        ONLINE_USERACCOUNT_ID, 
        ONLINE_ROOMS_DIRECTORY, 
        ONLINE_ROOMS_LIST, 
        ONLINE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT, 
        ONLINE_ROOMS_MANAGEMENT, 
        ONLINE_MAILINGLIST_DIRECTORY, 
        ONLINE_MAILINGLIST_LIST, 
        ONLINE_MAILINGLIST_MEMBERS, 
        ONLINE_MAILINGLIST_MANAGER, 
        ONLINE_PEOPLESEARCH_DIRECTORY 
    ) 
    VALUES 
    SELECT 
        ONLINE_USERACCOUNT_ID, 
        1, 
        1, 
        1, 
        1, 
        1, 
        1, 
        1, 
        1, 
        1 
    FROM INSERTED 

ELSE IF (SELECT ONLINE_PEOPLE_FULL_ACCESS FROM INSERTED) = 0 

    INSERT INTO dbo.WebOnlineUserPeopleDashboard 
    ( 
        ONLINE_USERACCOUNT_ID, 
        ONLINE_ROOMS_DIRECTORY, 
        ONLINE_ROOMS_LIST, 
        ONLINE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT, 
        ONLINE_ROOMS_MANAGEMENT, 
        ONLINE_MAILINGLIST_DIRECTORY, 
        ONLINE_MAILINGLIST_LIST, 
        ONLINE_MAILINGLIST_MEMBERS, 
        ONLINE_MAILINGLIST_MANAGER, 
        ONLINE_PEOPLESEARCH_DIRECTORY 
    ) 
    VALUES 
    SELECT 
        ONLINE_USERACCOUNT_ID, 
        0, 
        0, 
        0, 
        0, 
        0, 
        0, 
        0, 
        0, 
        0 
    FROM INSERTED 

ELSE 

    INSERT INTO dbo.WebOnlineUserPeopleDashboard 
    ( 
        ONLINE_USERACCOUNT_ID, 
        ONLINE_ROOMS_DIRECTORY, 
        ONLINE_ROOMS_LIST, 
        ONLINE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT, 
        ONLINE_ROOMS_MANAGEMENT, 
        ONLINE_MAILINGLIST_DIRECTORY, 
        ONLINE_MAILINGLIST_LIST, 
        ONLINE_MAILINGLIST_MEMBERS, 
        ONLINE_MAILINGLIST_MANAGER, 
        ONLINE_PEOPLESEARCH_DIRECTORY 
    ) 
        SELECT 
            ONLINE_USERACCOUNT_ID, 
            CASE --DIRECTORY 
                WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_FULL_ACCESS = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_VIEW = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_ADD = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_UPDATE = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_DELETE = 1 
                    THEN 1 
                WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_FULL_ACCESS = 0 
                    THEN 0 
            END, 
            CASE 
                WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_VIEW = 1 
                    THEN 1 
                WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_VIEW = 0  
                    THEN 0 
            END, 
            CASE 
                WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_ADD = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_UPDATE = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_DELETE = 1 
                    THEN 1 
                WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_ADD = 0 AND ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_UPDATE = 0 AND ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_DELETE = 0 
                    THEN 0 
            END, 
            CASE 
                WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_MANAGEMENT_FULL_ACCESS = 1 
                    THEN 1 
                WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_MANAGEMENT_FULL_ACCESS = 0 
                    THEN 0 
            END, 
            CASE 
                WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_FULL_ACCESS = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_VIEW = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_ADD = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_UPDATE = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_DELETE = 1 
                    THEN 1 
                WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_FULL_ACCESS = 0 
                    THEN 0 
            END, 
            CASE 
                WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_VIEW = 1 
                    THEN 1 
                WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_VIEW = 0 
                    THEN 0 
            END, 
            CASE 
                WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_ADD = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_UPDATE = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_DELETE = 1 
                    THEN 1 
                WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_ADD = 0 AND ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_UPDATE = 0 AND ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_DELETE = 0 
                    THEN 0 
            END, 
            CASE 
                WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_ADD = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_UPDATE = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_DELETE = 1 
                    THEN 1 
                WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_ADD = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_UPDATE = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_DELETE = 1 
                    THEN 0 
            END, 
            CASE 
                WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_PEOPLE_SEARCH = 1 
                    THEN 1 
                WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_PEOPLE_SEARCH = 0 
                    THEN 0 
            END 
        FROM INSERTED
```

Comment: Oh ok, so use an IF ELSE statement to encapsulate the entire insert statements. Completely understandable and logical. I will attempt that tomorrow morning when I get back into the office and let you know.

Thank you very much.

Comment: if you ever insert multiple rows at one time, this trigger will fail.

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you, This table is a single row insertion process so I will not have to worry about that for now. In my other tables i just might have to user the other example for multiple row insertions.

Comment: **NEVER code a trigger for single insertion** it will eventually bite you!  perhaps you app inserts only one today, what about some time in the future, maybe a year for now you'll have some script insert a bunch or you'll import a file, etc. **this trigger will not fail with an error and a rollback, but you will just get wrong data, which is way worse!**

Answer (score 2):

this will handle all rows if multiple rows are affected by the trigger:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.WebOnlineUserPeopleDashboard
    (
        ONLINE_USERACCOUNT_ID,
        ONLINE_ROOMS_DIRECTORY,
        ONLINE_ROOMS_LIST,
        ONLINE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT,
        ONLINE_ROOMS_MANAGEMENT,
        ONLINE_MAILINGLIST_DIRECTORY,
        ONLINE_MAILINGLIST_LIST,
        ONLINE_MAILINGLIST_MEMBERS,
        ONLINE_MAILINGLIST_MANAGER,
        ONLINE_PEOPLESEARCH_DIRECTORY
    )
SELECT
    ONLINE_USERACCOUNT_ID,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1
FROM INSERTED
WHERE ONLINE_PEOPLE_FULL_ACCESS=1
UNION
SELECT
    ONLINE_USERACCOUNT_ID,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
FROM INSERTED
WHERE ONLINE_PEOPLE_FULL_ACCESS=0
UNION
SELECT
    ONLINE_USERACCOUNT_ID,
    CASE --DIRECTORY
        WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_FULL_ACCESS = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_VIEW = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_ADD = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_UPDATE = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_DELETE = 1
            THEN 1
        WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_FULL_ACCESS = 0
            THEN 0
        --ELSE ???  what is the default
    END,
    CASE
        WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_VIEW = 1
            THEN 1
        WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_VIEW = 0 
            THEN 0
        --ELSE ???  what is the default
    END,
    CASE
        WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_ADD = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_UPDATE = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_DELETE = 1
            THEN 1
        WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_ADD = 0 AND ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_UPDATE = 0 AND ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_PLACEMENT_DELETE = 0
            THEN 0
        --ELSE ???  what is the default
    END,
    CASE
        WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_MANAGEMENT_FULL_ACCESS = 1
            THEN 1
        WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_ROOMS_MANAGEMENT_FULL_ACCESS = 0
            THEN 0
        --ELSE ???  what is the default
    END,
    CASE
        WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_FULL_ACCESS = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_VIEW = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_ADD = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_UPDATE = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_DELETE = 1
            THEN 1
        WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_FULL_ACCESS = 0
            THEN 0
        --ELSE ???  what is the default
    END,
    CASE
        WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_VIEW = 1
            THEN 1
        WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_VIEW = 0
            THEN 0
        --ELSE ???  what is the default
    END,
    CASE
        WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_ADD = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_UPDATE = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_DELETE = 1
            THEN 1
        WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_ADD = 0 AND ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_UPDATE = 0 AND ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_MEMBERS_DELETE = 0
            THEN 0
        --ELSE ???  what is the default
    END,
    CASE
        WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_ADD = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_UPDATE = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_DELETE = 1
            THEN 1
        WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_ADD = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_UPDATE = 1 OR ONLINE_PEOPLE_MAILING_LISTS_DELETE = 1
            THEN 0
        --ELSE ???  what is the default
    END,
    CASE
        WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_PEOPLE_SEARCH = 1
            THEN 1
        WHEN ONLINE_PEOPLE_PEOPLE_SEARCH = 0
            THEN 0
        --ELSE ???  what is the default
    END
FROM INSERTED
WHERE ONLINE_PEOPLE_FULL_ACCESS NOT IN (0,1)
```